# Publish Infopath Form MANUALLY to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Is there a way to publish Infopath form manually? I have an infopath form that I created for sharepoint on a computer. Now, I want to move that xsn file to another dev computer where sharepoint is installed but no infopath. So, I cant use the infopath publish options. Is there a way to MANUALLY PUBLISH?

What I have tried so far is to open the xsn file and read the xsf file. That did not work.

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks,

Comment: Please follow procedure I described [at the end of this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/how-to-reconnect-infopath-task-form-to-spd-workflow-after-moving-it-to-the-new-s/41551#41551)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went over the post, as well as other linked items. However, each post points out PUBLISH TO INFOPATH using infopath designer after having carried out the changes to the xsf manually. That is my issue.

I do not have access to InfoPath designer and need a way to publish it on the server.

THE END GOAL is: to associate this new form to a LIST. May be there is another way to achieve this? 

Thanks!

Comment: I guess the end question is: Can we PUBLISH infopath form without having Infopath designer installed? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to answer.
First, I did not understand what "MANUALLY" did mean... but forgot to ask.

My personal belief (from never ever sufficient experience) is that it is impossible to manually substitute the publishing (which is being done from Infopath Designer).

And the latter is proprietary undocumented about full details procedure dependent on sharepoint internals (with the latter also being proprietary and closed information).

Might be somebody else has another opinion.
Well, you can try... and report here back.

**Update:**
There are development suites (IDE, frameworks, extensions) where you can develop all from the scratch or use open source libraries, extensions (like .NET, MS SQL Server Business Intelligence) and the approaches where you should follow what is precompiled and closed for meddling like  Sharepoint and Infopath.

There are pro and contra in both.
In any case one should analyze and balance business requirements.

Anyway, I was a little puzzled by situation when you do not have Infopath installed on client machine.
In this case, you can use Infopath forms only through Infopath Forms Services of Sharepoint Server which is enterprise and rather expensive feature.

If you (or your client have it), then Infopath (which is part of Microsoft Office suite) is usually already bundled into all Microsoft plans or packages  having enterprise Sharepoint server.

There is also [Office 365 (Sharepoint Online)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/) 30-day free trials with all bundled.
Here is [comparison of plans and prices](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans-FX102918419.aspx).
When mine expired, I was getting warnings and proposals to buy but really continued to have access for more 4 months before my access was really cut.

It is a  marketing bluff that Infopath is easy. It is easy to start by clicking a few buttons and generate something ready but this easiness pays off dearly if you will be required to do something more flexible, customizable and/or not reqadily provided OOTB (very frequently used term in Sharepoint and Infopath, Out-Of-The_Box) in Sharepoint and IP when it happens that it is more difficult, more time consuming and more involved  then using development from scratch approaches

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Even though the answer is probably in the negative or a time consuming workaround hack to accomplish this, I did manage to learn a thing or two from your post. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, I like how you say "from never ever sufficient experience". Makes one wonder why the heck do they interview for at job interviews anyway when realistically speaking technology experience is never ever sufficient for anyone.

Comment: Thanks. Started to write a comment but then moved it to body of my answer.